# How do i pass properties from a child component to it's parent Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

In my parent i have a {{title}} and a {{subtitle}} that should change when my children changes (children should give his title and subtitle to parent), my children is rendered inside router-outlet, there will be various children components that give it's unique title and subtitle!
I have tryed various approaches but none is giving me a positive solution,
thanks in advance.
Parent HTML:

```
{{view_titular.title}} {{view_titular.subtitle}}

<div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>//Here's where my several children will load!
```

Children TS:

```
export class ChildrenComponent implements OnInit {
data: titular = { title: 'childrens title', subtitle: 'children subtitle' }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Use an event emitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using child as a selector then you should take one common service between parent and child.

common.service.ts

```
public data = new Subject<any>();
```

child.component.ts

```
this.commonService.data.next({
    title: 'Title',
    subTitle: 'Sub Title'
});
```

parent.component.ts

```
title = '';
subTitle = '';
constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
    commonService.data.subscribe(data => {
       this.title = data.title;
       this.subTitle = data.subTitle;
    });
}
```

**To Solve ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError> error, you use any of the below 2 solution.**

**1**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    commonService.data.subscribe(data => {
       this.title = data.title;
       this.subTitle = data.subTitle;
    });
});
```

**2**

```
   commonService.data.pipe(
      delay(0),
      tap((data) => {
         this.title = data.title;
         this.subTitle = data.subTitle;
      })
  ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Seems like this is working, but it gets me this error, Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError> Expression has changed after it was checked.

Comment: Find the edited answer to solve is error. Even this error won't come when you build and deploy you code. if you want you can ignore this error.

Comment: I think im doing something wrong, sometimes my app gets the variables with the data i pass from my children, but my html doesn't reflect it.. this might be related to this error

Comment: No displaying in html is not related to this error.

Comment: i tryed using a pipe and the title and subtitle in my parent already have the data, but it's not showing it, any idea why?

Comment: can you please share you code in stackblitz so i can help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2sx9o?embed=1&file=src/app/layout/layout.component.html does this work? i never used stackblitz, sorry

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wequzu please find the solution in the given link.

Comment: hope you get the solution. please let me know for anything else. thanks

Comment: Thanks so much!, that stackblitz answer hit the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link. They have a comprehensive explanation.[Here](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Comment: Yes i have tryed those, but none is working for my case

Answer (score 0):

Use EventEmitter to share the data

In child component .ts file.

```
 @Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() { }

  sendMessage() {
    this.childEvent .emit({title,subTitle});
  }
```

In parent .html file

```
<app-child (childEvent)="receiveData($event)"></app-child>
```

In parent .ts file

```
receiveData($event) {
    this.title= $event.title;
this.title= $event.subTitle;
  }
```

Comment: This is not working due to me rendering child in route-outlet, im not using selector